# Problem with restarting when append with marquee js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, marquee

I append the marquee it starts to slide but as soon as the first start comes to an end, it restarts then
the flow continues as I want

What should I do to avoid restarting at first startup?

javascript sample code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const endPoint = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
  const data = {
    name: "Zorg",
    job: "Handyman"
  };
 
    $.post(endPoint, data, function (data, status) {
      if (status == "success") {
        console.log(data);
        $('marquee').append(JSON.stringify(data));
      } else {
        console.log(`Error ${status}`);
      }
    });

});
```

html marquee part

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" width="auto"></marquee>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const endPoint = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
      const data = {
        name: "Zorg",
        job: "Handyman"
      };
     
        $.post(endPoint, data, function (data, status) {
          if (status == "success") {
            console.log(data);
            $('marquee').append(JSON.stringify(data));
          } else {
            console.log(`Error ${status}`);
          }
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" width="auto"></marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that Chromiums marquee is a bit buggy.

You can recreate this effect with CSS. There are several examples out there.

Here is one from [w3schools.in](https://htmleditor.w3schools.in/?filename=html_css_scrolling_text_using_css):

```css
.marquee {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #fefefe;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
}

.marquee p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <p> Marquee in CSS </p>
</div>
```